# BindItem to SelectedValue not working ( Item is working )

Tags: asp.net, webforms, enums, model-binding

I have Enum defined in a separate class as follows:

```
public static class BudgetDescriptions
{
  public enum Months
    {
        January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November,    December
    };
}
```

Im trying to 2 way bind this Enum to SelectedValue of DropDown. It works when I use Item ( which is one-way binding) like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server"
SelectMethod="GetMonths"
DataTextField="Text"
DataValueField="Value"
SelectedValue='<%#
Convert.ToString((int)
(HomeBudgetASP.BudgetDescriptions.Months)
Enum.Parse(typeof(HomeBudgetASP.BudgetDescriptions.Months),
Item.Date.ToString()))
%>'
CssClass="form-control" ID="ddlMonth">
```

For SelectedValue im converting to Enum using Parse with Item.Date as current value.

This works fine.

However, when I change Item to **BindItem**:

```
SelectedValue='<%#
Convert.ToString((int)
(HomeBudgetASP.BudgetDescriptions.Months)
Enum.Parse(typeof(HomeBudgetASP.BudgetDescriptions.Months),
BindItem.Date.ToString()))
%>'
```

im getting following error when trying access webpage:

**Invalid code syntax for BindItem.**

So im wondering, any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that when using BindItem we are unable to convert data type. So BindItem.Date.ToString() wont work.

Solution is to revert back to Bind("Date") pre ASP.NET 4.5 style for this one.